# Is there any captcha angular directive that doesn't require backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, captcha, recaptcha

I have pure angular app (no backend code).
I have a call to third party REST API from javascript but I want to add captcha before submit.
I tried to implement [reCaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/start) but it require backend.
Is there some captcha directive that doesn't involve server side code validation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A captcha is used to prevent a lot of hostile requests or form submissions to a server. Usually these would be generated directly by the attacker without actually running your intervening code on the client side (or by running it once and then modifying the submitted data).

Therefore anything that looked like a captcha that you embedded in your client code would likely be bypassed by the attacker and would not provide any protection. For a captcha to do anything useful it must involve server-side verification.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I understand it but in my case I also have a form but those data I send to third party API (from JS) which will ban me if I send too many requests to it. That is why I need captcha. And if not captcha what could be good protection? - or the only protection is to write my own server side code and avoid JS call to API?

Comment: If you're worried about requests from a single client then you can write client-side code to throttle the requests. If the total number of requests from multiple clients is a problem then you may have to proxy the requests through another server.

Comment: I need single client check can you give me some idea of what I can try?